# Python: Добавление элемента в список в списке JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

У меня есть JSON файл:

```
{
    "Chats": [
        {
            "id": "321",
            "users": [
                {
                    "first_name": "first_name",
                    "id": "123",
                    "screenname": "lol",
                    "last_name": "last_name",
                    "sex": "1",
                    "urltovk": "https://vk.com/id123"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Можно ли с помощью python в список users добавить элементы по id из Chats?
Должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

```
{
    "Chats": [
        {
            "id": "123123",
            "users": [
                {
                    "first_name": "first_name",
                    "id": "123",
                    "screenname": "lol",
                    "last_name": "last_name",
                    "sex": "1",
                    "urltovk": "https://vk.com/id123"
                },
                {
                    "first_name": "first_name2",
                    "id": "1232",
                    "screenname": "lol2",
                    "last_name": "last_name2",
                    "sex": "2",
                    "urltovk": "https://vk.com/id1232"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Дайте пример того, что хочется получить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
import pprint

with open('test.json') as f:
    obj = json.load(f)

data = {
    "first_name": "first_name2",
    "id": "1232",
    "screenname": "lol2",
    "last_name": "last_name2",
    "sex": "2",
    "urltovk": "https://vk.com/id1232"
}

obj['Chats'][0]['users'].append(data)

pprint.pprint(obj)
```

Вывод:

```
{'Chats': [{'id': '321',
            'users': [{'first_name': 'first_name',
                       'id': '123',
                       'last_name': 'last_name',
                       'screenname': 'lol',
                       'sex': '1',
                       'urltovk': 'https://vk.com/id123'},
                      {'first_name': 'first_name2',
                       'id': '1232',
                       'last_name': 'last_name2',
                       'screenname': 'lol2',
                       'sex': '2',
                       'urltovk': 'https://vk.com/id1232'}]}]}
```

Comment: а можно ли узнать ['Chats'][число]['users'] по id из Chats?

Comment: не совсем понимаю ваш вопрос. возможно вам нужно проверить все элементы списка  ['Chats'][число] в цикле. на каждой итерации сравнивать ['Chats'][число]['id'] с нужным значением, если найдено совпадение, то выводить ['Chats'][число]['users']

Comment: я про то что если так сказать чатов будет 2 и нужно будет добавить в конкретный из них то как определить в какой именно?

Comment: Я же написал выше. Цикл по всем чатам `for chat in obj['Chats']`. В цикле условие `if chat['id'] == нужный_id`, то `print(chat['users'])`. Ну и `break` можно сразу, если вас только один чат интересует.

Comment: да именно это и нужно) спасибо вам